# PayPal Express Checkout PHP not getting a response

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, paypal

I'm currently trying to get PayPal express checkout working using the angelleye codeigniter library (https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-codeigniter). I'm not getting a response or any errors from PayPal. The only error I am getting is an undefined index of ACK due to there not being a response. There are not any curl errors and the PayPal response comes back with an empty array.

Is there a way of checking where this is failing?

Running on:

Ubuntu 12.04.5

curl 7.37.0

PHP 5.5.32

Apache 2.4.12

OpenSSL 1.0.1

Comment: Make Sure Your PHP version is 5.6 or above that's a problem . i also had this kind of problem before ...

Comment: That's interesting because I have PHP 5.5.32 and it works fine for me, @AmitChauhan can you clarify what about PHP 5.6 made it work for you? It was my understanding with Curl 7.36 + you could use the new PayPal API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In /application/libraries/paypal/Paypal_pro.php find the CURLRequest() function.  Should be at line 589.

After this line in the function:

```
$Response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Add the following, add the following:

```
if($Response === FALSE) {
  echo "cURL Error: " . curl_error($curl);
  exit();
}
```

Then run another test. If there is a curl error happening you should be able to see it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have just run that and this is what came back `cURL Error: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure`

Comment: Ok, that means you are running into the [POODLE problem](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vulnerability/).  The software stack you've outlined, though, shouldn't have that problem.  Can you double check all of that?  Can you add a file with phpinfo() on your server for review?

Comment: After checking my `phpinfo()` php was only referencing curl 7.32 despite having 7.37.0 installed. I am in the process of upgrading the php curl package. Hopefully this should work.

Comment: I am now running 7.37.0 and am getting a response from PayPal. However, the response I am getting an error back which is 10002  Security header is not valid. I have tried with the api username and password of both the buyer and facilitator account and I get the same error. Do you have any idea what would be causing this?

Comment: That error always means the API credentials are wrong.  That means the values themselves are wrong, or it could be that you're sending sandbox credentials to the live server or vice-versa.

Comment: Right ok, I have checked the sandbox credentials and I was using the live credentials on sandbox. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I am getting this response after the line added   cURL Error: Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received