# Unable to get curl response from codeigniter paypal library

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, paypal

I have checked the answer to this post

[paypal codeigniter library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429393/paypal-express-checkout-php-not-getting-a-response)

but i am getting this error cURL Error: Operation timed out after 30000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received.

can someone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the timeout manually

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 500); // timeout in seconds
```